# Execute command on another host using GitLab Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I'm new to the CI/CD world and currently learning.
Here is my current setup:

- installation of windows 11
- a folder containing a project called "blog" (This folder is representing a development folder)
- a folder containing a project called "blog1" (This folder is representing a server that can't be written, other than through `git pull`)
- a working GitLab Runner
- gitlab-ci.yml (most of the contents are from gitlab tutorial)

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Pulling changes"
    - cd C:\xampp\htdocs\blog1
    - git config --global --add safe.directory C:\xampp\htdocs\blog1
    - git pull origin main

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

The script works fine because the GitLab Runner and the target folder are on the same host,
[current setup working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWNXE.png)
but what if the target folder is on different host (let's say another Windows PC), how do I achive the same functionality with the runner and target folder being on different host ?

I tried reproducing the functionality through SSH.

1. connect to SSH using powershell `ssh username@IPADDRESS`
2. type password
3. change directory to target folder
4. git pull inside the target folder

How do I implement it inside the build script ?. Ideally I don't want any password on the gitlab-ci.yml file.

Thank you

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all seems a bit off:

1. The Runner does its own git pull. This places the files in something like <runner-build-directory\projectpath> and this also is the working directory for the pipeline.
   Which leads us to:
2. Use relative paths for the build. So no matter on what runner the build is running it will still find your stuff. This also allows us to:
3. **[Use Artefacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html)** This will package selected files and allows them to be used by different stages of the build(e.g. the deploy step) [See here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#dependencies) . You can also download them from Gitlab if you deploy by hand.
4. If the target machine is not running the ... runner you can use SSH/SFTP to transfer the files to the target during deploy. You should not write your ssh passwords into the YML. Gitlab has [Ci variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#define-a-cicd-variable-in-the-ui) for this.

This all makes only fully sense if you have a real build step. I.e. one that generates new files. Right now you could skip directly to the deploy and push the files in the working directory of the runner to the target via SFTP.